# When to use ManyToOne and ManyToMany relationships

Tags: python, django-models, many-to-many, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

The below is a database of colleges, and its ratings. The below is how I thought

1. Each Class (Batch, ex: Batch of 2009) belongs to a Department
2. Each Department (ex: department of pharmacy) belongs to a College

As I am particularly concerned about Ratings. I thought to Rate a Batch, there by using a Manager or some Model Method, I can calculate Total Department or College Ratings.

1. Each Class has Ratings

Note: There may be many ratings by different Users for a single Class. So, I guess Total or Average ratings should be done by a Method!

This is how I so far did

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    positive = models.FloatField(default=0)
    negative = models.FloatField(default=0)

class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    website = models.URLField()

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College)

class Batch(models.Model):
    passout_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    rating = models.ForeignKey(Rating)
```

This schema has some issues!

- Each Batch can only have single rating! However, I am looking for multiple ratings signed by many Users (Though Users model is not integrated yet)
- Each Batch belongs to a Department, Each Department belongs to a College. However, we can also think of the relationships in another way
- Each College has many Departments, Each Department has many Batches While.. Each Batch has Many Departments (ex: there may be many departments in 2009), and Each Department can be in Many colleges

So, should I use ManyToManyField instead of ForeignKey?

How should I schema should look like?

One of the most essential changes I think are

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    ..
    ..
    user = models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User)

class College(models.Model):
    ..
    ..
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)

class Department(models.Model):
    ..
    college = models.ForeignKey(College)
    batches = models.ManyToManyField(Batch)

class Batch(models.Model):
    ..
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    rating = models.ManyToMany(Rating)
```

Is this going to be right? How should it look if if not

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User#First import user
lass Rating(models.Model):
    ..
    ..
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class College(models.Model):
    ..
    ..
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)

class Department(models.Model):
    ..
    college = models.ForeignKey(College)
    batches = models.ManyToManyField(Batch)

class Batch(models.Model):
    ..
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    rating = models.ManyToMany(Rating)
```

When you make many to many relationship a bridge entity is automatically created by Django.

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my answer (below).. Is that right?

Comment: Department has ManyToMany(batch) and batch has ForeignKey to Department.. is that going into some trouble

Comment: Nope. One table can be related to one or more than one table, right? Your Department will have two foreign keys and one primary key. That's not the thing to worry.